# Can you call a class from another class?

Tags: php, oop

Im currently learning oop from youtube etc and ive started my first project using it. The question i have that hasn't been answered along the way is..

say i have two classes

```
class a{
  public function dosomething($var){

  }
}
```

and

```
class b{
}
```

Can i access dosomething function from class b? if so could someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: if public, static(not instanced) yes given that $var is an instance of b

Comment: Could you give me an example or a link that shows this as i dont fully understand how the syntax would look like? Cheers

Comment: This is the direction you should follow: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Pass instance of class `a` to class `b` and call method on that. (advisable)
2. Make method in class `a` static and call it like `a::method()`. (you should never do this)

To solve problem with the first way, your `b` class needs slight modification:

```
class b{
    public function callMethodOfClassa(a $instanceOfa, $var) {
        $instanceOfa->dosomething($var);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
class b {
    private $property;

    public function callMethodOfClassa($var) {
       $this->property->dosomething($var);
    }

    public function __construct(a $instanceOfa) {
        $this->property = $instanceOfa;
    }
}
```

In the second example you keep reference to passed instance in a field called `$property` here and is passed when instance of `b` is initialized:

```
$instanceOfa = new a();
$instanceOfb = new b($instanceOfa);
```

For better understanding of object oriented programming with php read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

And promised [demo for the first example](http://ideone.com/oTiuq7) [demo for the second sample](http://ideone.com/S5rk4z) (*for better understanding made name changes*).

Comment: Could you give me an example or a link that shows this as i dont fully understand how the syntax would look like? Cheers

Comment: Thanks for that, ill have to have a play about as the oop stuff is still new to me so this looks a bit confusing.

Comment: @Ian You are welcome. I'll update my answer with working demos. Also keep names clear for the next time. `a` and `b` are quite tiring to write and easy to mess up something. ;)

Comment: ill bare that in mind but a and b were just example names lol. Thanks very much

Comment: @Ian Take a look at demo as well. ;)

Comment: Brillant thanks that makes sense now!! Cheers for your time a lot of people wouldn't bother. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Ian You are welcome. Anyhow, this question will be closed due to lacking minimal understanding of the problem. Next time I'd recommend to read manual first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Detailed explenation from comment:

```
  class a{
      public function dosomething(b $var){
        $var->dosomething2();
      }
      public static function dosomething3(b $var){
        $var->dosomething2();
      }
    }
    and

    class b{
      public function dosomething2(a $var){
         echo 'Hi, not doing anithing with this var!';
      }
    }


usage:
$variable1 = new a();
$variable2 = new b();
$variable1->dosomething($variable2);
a::dosomething3($variable2);          //static call, no instance
$variable2->dosomething2($variable2);
```